# why can I not open .exe programs with wine?

Tags: macos, wine

today I downloaded a game for windows called "koikatsu party" When I try to open it with wine. I can't open it, There's an error called "prefix creation exited with error wine". After that I thought it was an error of the game so to try I've downloaded "Sonnic" also for windows and the same problems appears again
can somebody help me?

```
 enter code her###BOTTLING### customprefix.sh
/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 39: /private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
###BOTTLING### Gathering debug Info...

Versions
OS...........................: darwin20
Wine.........................: 
WineBottler..................: 1.8.6
Wineticks....................: 20210206-next - sha256sum: 68c7bc5a665ea54a53fd66d97cb9f1c540b9a6ff7475b4f38e64f7e1500bf43c

Environment
PWD..........................: '/private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin'
PATH.........................: /private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
USER.........................: desarrollo
HOME.........................: /Users/desarrollo
COMPUTERNAME.................: MacBook Pro de desarrollo
BUNDLERESOURCEPATH...........: /var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources
WINEPREFIX...................: /private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources
WINEPATH.....................: /private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH..............: /private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/opt/X11/lib:/usr/X11/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...: /private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/X11/lib:/usr/X11/lib
SILENT.......................: 
http_proxy...................: 
https_proxy..................: 
ftp_proxy....................: 
socks5_proxy.................: 

Bottle
TEMPLATE.....................: 
BOTTLE.......................: /Users/desarrollo/Wine Files
INSTALLER_URL................: 
INSTALLER_IS_ZIPPED..........: 0
INSTALLER_NAME...............: 
INSTALLER_ARGUMENTS..........: 
REMOVE_MONO..................: 
REMOVE_GECKO.................: 
REMOVE_USERS.................: 
REMOVE_INSTALLERS............: 
WINETRICKS_ITEMS.............: 
DLL_OVERRIDES................: 
EXECUTABLE_PATH..............: notneeded
EXECUTABLE_ARGUMENTS.........: 
EXECUTABLE_VERSION...........: 1.0.0
BUNDLE_COPYRIGHT.............: 
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER............: org.kronenberg.winebottler
BUNDLE_CATEGORYTYPE..........: public.app-category.utilities
SILENT.......................: 

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,3
      Processor Name: Quad-Core Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2,3 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 4
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 6 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 16 GB
      System Firmware Version: 429.0.0.0.0
      SMC Version (system): 2.19f12
      Serial Number (system): C02LJ0GDFD57
      Hardware UUID: 66B9A6B2-F768-5965-9EE8-4A9FA241C92B
      Provisioning UDID: 66B9A6B2-F768-5965-9EE8-4A9FA241C92B

###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat menus...
/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 134: /private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
### LOG ### Command '/private/var/folders/sg/ymcwh7gn66n0hm811hzs_74c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E36F0F8A-FA20-446B-AA6D-B2AE722C6AA1/d/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.



Task returned with status 1.
```

I've tried to redownload wine but it also doesn't work.
I am using wine for most windows games.